# Upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 - Libtool

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to upgrade from ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0.

I ran

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p448 2.0.0-p247
```

The error I get is:

```
Error running 'requirements_smf_lib_install libtool',
please read /Users/melanie/.rvm/log/1381637445_ruby-2.0.0-p247/package_install_libtool.log
Failed installation package: libtool of: libtool, gdbm.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Unable to install ruby ruby-2.0.0-p247. Please install it manually to continue.
```

My log says:

```
[2013-10-13 15:11:58] requirements_smf_lib_install
requirements_smf_lib_install () 
{ 
    typeset -a __smf_install_command;
    requirements_smf_lib_install_command "$@";
    rvm_debug "__smf_install_command: ${__smf_install_command[*]};";
    "${__smf_install_command[@]}" || { 
        typeset ret=$?;
        rvm_warn "There were package installation errors with SM Framework, make sure to read the log.
If you see this on OSX, then you might want to try macports (http://www.macports.org/) or homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and tell RVM to use them by running:

    rvm autolibs macports #OR
    rvm autolibs homebrew

You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm";
        return $ret
    };
    shift
}
current path: /Users/melanie
command(2): requirements_smf_lib_install libtool
  [ ] libtool 2.4.2 ~ dependencies... 

  [[32m✔[0m] libtool 2.4.2 ~ dependencies   
  [ ] libtool 2.4.2 ~ fetch... curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory


  [[32m✔[0m] libtool 2.4.2 ~ fetch   

FAIL(paths): Path '/opt/sm/src/libtool-2.4.2' does not exist.

   +#   source file                                                    # function()                                        
================================================================================
vi +330 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/log/functions                            # __sm.log.fail                                        
vi +32  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/paths/functions                    # __sm.paths.enter                                        
vi +144 /opt/sm/core/api/shell/paths/functions                         # paths                                        
vi +54  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/package/strategies/gnu/functions   # __sm.package.gnu.install                                        
vi +15  /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/package/functions                  # __sm.package.install                                        
vi +143 /opt/sm/core/api/shell/package/functions                       # package                                        
vi +403 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/log/functions                            # __sm.actions.call                                        
vi +178 /opt/sm/core/internal/shell/extensions/execution/functions     # __sm.extension.run                                        
vi +151 /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/core/initialize                          # /opt/sm/core/sm/shell/core/initialize                                        
vi +41  /opt/sm/bin/sm                                                 # /opt/sm/bin/sm                                        
================================================================================
There were package installation errors with SM Framework, make sure to read the log.
If you see this on OSX, then you might want to try macports (http://www.macports.org/) or homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and tell RVM to use them by running:

    rvm autolibs macports #OR
    rvm autolibs homebrew

You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

How do I resolve the issues so that I can upgrade using RVM. Alternatively, how do i install manually?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Homebrew installed?

Comment: No, I dont have Homebrew.

Comment: You're missing a Ruby dependency that's better installed with Homebrew. Once you have Homebrew, RVM will be able to install all your dependencies automatically. http://brew.sh/

Comment: Homebrew was giving me other trouble, so I removed it. Do you know if there is another way to find the dependent files? Thank you.

Comment: Homebrew is the easier way. It's the best package manager for OS X and it's pretty mature by now. I know it may be a pain to install, but trust me -- the alternatives are worse.

Comment: Don't forget to install the XCode Command Line Tools first: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Thanks both. I have xcode command line tools. I'm really reluctant about Homebrew. Do you know if there is an alternative to using it?

Comment: I've now just installed homebrew, tried again, and gotten the same error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: `rvm get stable --autolibs=enabled` or you can manually install libtool by using `brew install libtool`

Comment: Or go ahead and install the whole set of Ruby dependencies: `brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba`

Answer (score 0):

rvm lets you have all the versions and then you switch between them for whichever interpreter you want to run your code against.

Use `rvm install 2.0` to install Ruby 2.0.

Use `rvm use 2.0` to use it

Use `rvm use 2.0 --default` to set it as the default

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error when I run rvm install 2.0.0, being:    Error running 'requirements_smf_lib_install libtool',
please read /Users/melanie/.rvm/log/1381640713_ruby-2.0.0-p247/package_install_libtool.log
Failed installation package: libtool of: libtool, gdbm.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.